# Linq to XML query problem

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a `List<Item>` collection that I am trying to generate an xml file from using Linq to XML.

The List class is below:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
}
```

I need to get XML that looks like this:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Item_Name>Super Sale Item Name</Item_Name>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Here's the query I tried but am having no luck getting to work

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Items"),
          _myItemCollection.Select(x => new XElement("Item",
                                            new XElement("ID", x.Id),
                                            new XElement("Item_Name", x.ItemName))));
```

I keep getting an error saying it would create invalid XML.  Any ideas?

Error is

This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.

at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateDocument(XNode previous, XmlNodeType allowBefore, XmlNodeType allowAfter)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateNode(XNode node, XNode previous)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddNodeSkipNotify(XNode n)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument..ctor(Object[] content)

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact error you are having?

Comment: I added it there, there's not much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var collection = new[]
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, ItemName = "Super Sale Item Name"}
        };

        var xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Items",
                                collection.Select(x => new XElement("Item",
                                        new XElement("ID", x.Id),
                                        new XElement("Item_Name", x.ItemName)))));

        Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
    }
}
```

The main thing you are missing is that the project of your collection to `XElement` needs to be nested in the first `XElement` ("Items") rather than it's sibling.  Notice that `new XElement("Items")...` is changed to `new XElement("Items", ...`

Comment: That was it, had to remove that ) and it worked fine.  Thanks.

Comment: This should work, in your code you have an `XDocument` with different roots which is apparently not right.

Answer (score 1):

You're closing your first XElement too early:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Items",
            items.Select(i => new XElement("Item",
                                new XElement("ID", i.Id),
                                new XElement("Name", i.Name)))));
```